# How to use call_user_func in PHP

Tags: php, php-5.3

Hi `call_user_func` is used in my existing code but it is throwing an `INTERNAL SERVER ERROR`

```
$out=call_user_func($func);
```

`$func` variable has an array like this.

```
Array
    (
        [0] => MetricName Object
            (
                [idplot] => 
                [_idtestType:MetricName:private] => 
                [data] => 
                [idmetricName] => 
                [queriesForIds:MetricName:private] => Array
                    (
                        [idviewType] => SELECT column FROM Table WHERE idColumn = 
                        [idworstCase] => SELECT column2 FROM Table2 WHERE idColumn = 
                    )

            )

        [1] => update
    )


class MetricName { 
    function update() { 
      //Its not possible to add the code inside the update method
    }
}
```

This method is throwing `INTERNAL SERVER ERROR`

```
Undefined index: environment
```

Don't know how to fix this error.

Comment: Read logs and find more descriptive error text. `INTERNAL SERVER ERROR` __explains nothing__.

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error is a generic error message informing you that the server crashed while processing the request. Beyond that, it's meaningless, and is of very little use for debugging. You need to check the error logs on the server to try and find the underlying exception message. Once you've got that, you stand a chance of identifying the problem. P.S. if you don't have error logging set up yet, then please read this guide to configure it: https://stackify.com/php-error-logs-guide/

Comment: Also, you've tagged PHP 5.3. Why are you still using such an old, unsupported version? End of life for 5.3 was in 2014! (see https://www.php.net/eol.php). You are opening your application to unnecessary security risks. You should plan to upgrade as soon as possible. see https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

Answer (score 0):

How to use function call_user_func_array
reference visite https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.call-user-func-array.php

```
<?php
class MetricName { 
    function update($ds) { 
     print_r($ds);
    }
}

$func =  [
  new MetricName(),'update',
];

call_user_func_array ($func,['234']);
?>
```

Comment: Hi @Danilo Santos, Can you please write the code which suits my scenario, I added the array I have and the class and method which needs to be called. 
I have an object and I need to pass that object.

Comment: See if it meets your demand, if you don't try to give more details than you need